# ArcGIS Online Layers not updating and stuck loading when adding data with CSV file

Tags: arcgis-online, update, arcgis-portal, feature-service

My organization just recently (June 14th -15th 2023) experienced an update to the process of updating data already housed in a feature service layer.  Normally I add the data to a .csv file using a template that I have been using previously.

What I am experiencing is when I click the "Update Data" button the user interface has changed slightly with the latest update.  However, now the .csv file will not load and update the layer. It is getting stuck at this screen:

[image]

After it eventually times out, there is a new exported .csv file with the feature layer name and a long code of random numbers and letters. (Ex.[layer_name]22c46481-96e4-b27e-7571-76520bdef929)

I have had problems with this before. Sometimes the servers are slow, or sometimes I have invalid data.  I have never had it export out a .csv file of the layer's data before.

What are the possible solutions to solving this matter?